# Timed Event Priority Queue with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, priority-queue

Consider the following Scenario:

- There is a website, where users are able to initiate Actions
- each action has a specified duration, somewhere between 10 and 60 minutes
- finished actions have to be processed immediately, because they alter the view of other users

And now I am wondering how to implement this - I obviously need some kind of priority queue where I can asynchronously to page requests process events whose timeframes have ended.
Unfortunately, I have only plain php and mysql at my disposal, because the code is running in a webhosting environment, so I can't really use some fancy background daemon for this.
I have a couple of ideas using a mysql table as event queue, and polling events from this table on each page request, but this will eventually run into concurrency problems, unless I do it properly, which I don't know how.

Is there a simple way of solving this, that I am just overlooking because of overengineering, or am I stuck using some sort of mysql mechanism, and if so, how would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: note that if you can run php you can run php frameworks without too much hassle.

Comment: Btw, why was this flagged as "too broad"? Would the flagger please elaborate :)

Comment: I'm not the flagger, but I think that it is quite too broad because this community isn't fit for "How to" questions but more like "I've picked tool X and algorithm Y to achieve Z but it doesn't work, here's a relevant snipped of my code. Why it doesn't work?"

Comment: @STTLCU that would be a pretty poor practice for a QA site - I have a very specific problem, but I am not sure which of the technologies I have at my disposal are capable of producing an adequate solution, that does not seem too broad for me. Actually, I really expected to have overlooked something simple and that someone would come up with a really easy answer in like 5 minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else ever has this problem - I will draft out my solution here.

The main idea is, that I wanted to be able to asynchronously call specific functions after a specified time, with a given set of arguments.

For this, I first create a unique identifier from hashing all the relevant information of the asynchronous call. This identifier is used as primary key in a table of running actions in the database, containing the necessary fields in plain text.

The actual asynchronous call is then queued using the unix command `at` for minute precision, and the command `sleep` for second precision. The queued command is a `curl` call to a webpage on the current server, that takes the identifier as an argument and calls the function in the databased, that is referenced by the given identifier, if any.

this is an excerpt of the queue function that I use:

```
  public static function queue($name, $seconds, $function, $args = array())
  {
    $args_str = serialize($args);

    $identifier = sha512(USER::name() . "#" . SCRIPT_START . "#" . $seconds . "#" . $function . "#" . $args_str);

    $command = 'echo "sleep ' . ($seconds % 60) . '; curl http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/async.php?identifier=' . $identifier . '" | at now+' . floor($seconds / 60) . 'minutes &>/dev/null; echo $?';
    $res = shell_exec($command);
    if ($res != 0)
      {
        // [ ... ] error handling
      }

    DB::query("
      insert into actions
          (`identifier`, `name`, `account_id`, `end_time`, `function`, `args`)
        values
          ('" . DB::escape($identifier) . "',
           '" . DB::escape($name) . "',
           '" . DB::escape(USER::id()) . "',
           '" . ceil(SCRIPT_START + $seconds) . "',
           '" . DB::escape($function) . "',
           '" . DB::escape($args_str) . "')");

    return 0;
  }
```

In the `curl`ed webpage, I retrieve function and args from the row matching the given identifier, and call

```
call_user_func($action['function'], unserialize($action['args']));
```

which evauates the given string as a function call.

This together allows for asynchronous calls to stateless functions, but it requires that the www-data / apache user has access to the unix `at` command, but I think that is reasonable. In terms of security, I think that if properly used, this approach can not be tampered with by malevolent users, unless they're somehow able to guess the hashes.